# Read all system's drive data in network using python

Tags: python, wmi

I am making one app using python. In that I am not able to read files data of remote system. someone tell me how to read all computer's data in network using python.

And i have made remote connection using wmi module but through wmi, i can't access remote computer data.

```
import wmi

ip = '192.168.3.124'
username = 'example'
password = 'example'
try:
   connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
except:
   print "connection failed"
```

Comment: I have edited my post with code

Comment: `exceept`? Have you tested this?

Comment: by mistake in typing i have written. it is `except`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By wmi module it's not possible to read all files of network system but we can read by two ways

1) Mount remote system drive in to your local system.

2) set netuse virtual connection and access files

**For mounting remote system drive in your local system, use below code**

```
import win32api
import win32net
import win32netcon,win32wnet

username='user'
password='psw'

try:
    win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 'Z:','\\\\192.168.1.18\\D$', None, username,password, 0)
    print "connection established successfully"
except:
    print  "connection not established"
```

**After connection you can read all files data**

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('\\\\192.168.1.18\D$'):
        for filename in filenames:
            match=os.path.join(root, filename)
            datafile = file(match)
            for line in datafile:
               print line
```

**2) for set virtual connection use below code**

```
import win32api
import win32net

ip = '192.168.1.18'
username = 'ram'
password = 'ram@123'

try:
    use_dict={}
    use_dict['remote']=unicode('\\\\192.168.1.18\C$')
    use_dict['password']=unicode(password)
    use_dict['username']=unicode(username)
    win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 2, use_dict)
except:
    print  "connection not established"
```

Comment: It's working and i m able to read but i don't want to mount in local system. can you describe virtual netuse also.

Comment: I have updated code with virtual netuse connection. now you can access all computer data in network.